# Bring element forward (Z Index) in Silverlight/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

All the documentation and examples I'm finding online for setting Z-Index to bring an element forward in Silverlight are using a Canvas element as a container.

My items are Border elements inside of an ItemsControl container in a DataTemplate.  I'm using the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to trigger an animation on the ScaleTransform.ScaleX and ScaleTransform.ScaleY so they grow when hovered.  As they're resized and occupying the same space as other items in the container(s), the most recently added items are overlapping the older items (as opposed to the currently resizing item).  Is there a CLEAN way to bring the current item forward in code where I trigger my animation so that they overlap all other items when they're resized?

Answer (score 34):

I've had to deal with this.

Say you have an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate set to an instance of a custom control. Within that control you do Canvas.SetZIndex(this, 99). It won't work, because "this" is not the immediate child of the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel. The ItemsControl creates a ContentPresenter for each item, drops that into the ItemsPanel, and renders the ItemTemplate within the ContentPresenter.

So, if you want to change the ZIndex within your control, you have to find its ContentPresenter, and change the ZIndex on that. One way is...

```
        public static T FindVisualParent<T>( this DependencyObject obj )
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( obj );
        while ( parent != null )
        {
            T typed = parent as T;
            if ( typed != null )
            {
                return typed;
            }
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( parent );
        }
        return null;
    }
                ContentPresenter foo = this.FindVisualParent<ContentPresenter>();
            Canvas.SetZIndex( foo, 99 );
```

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors, this works. I tried setting the ZIndex from Silverlight Spy 3 (which I tried to inspect this all), but that apparently doesn't set the ZIndex (it keeps going back to 0). Finding the ContentPresenter using this helper did the trick.

Comment: Worked on this for days before finding this post.  Unlike Bart, the code worked pretty much as is for me.

PS: You can change the FindVisualParent function to a normal function, if you don't want to use extension methods, by changing its function prototype to "public static T FindVisualParent<t>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject"  You then invoke the new method by calling ContentPresenter foo = this.FindVisualParent<ContentPresenter>(this);

Comment: I pretty much followed this pattern, and I can see that my custom pushpin's content presenter is being updated with a higher ZIndex. However, i'm still not seeing my pushpin z-ordered correctly. Im using Silverlight 4.0. I set the ZIndex to be 99 and then set back to 0 based on mouse-enter/mouse-leave. Did something change to cause this to not work perhaps?

Answer (score 17):

In WPF there is the [Panel.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) property that you can set in a trigger:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="colors" Type="{x:Type Color}">
            <Color>Green</Color>
            <Color>Red</Color>
            <Color>Blue</Color>
            <Color>Orange</Color>
            <Color>Yellow</Color>
            <Color>Violet</Color>
        </x:Array>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Color}">
            <Border x:Name="brd" Height="20" Width="20">
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}"/>
                </Border.Background>
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform CenterX="10" CenterY="10"/>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
                <Border.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                               <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="brd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1.5"/>
                               <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="brd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                               <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="brd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1"/>
                               <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="brd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                  </EventTrigger>
                </Border.Triggers>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="99999"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource colors}" Margin="20" Width="40">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

In the `Style` for `ContentPresenter` we set the `Panel.ZIndex` to 99999 when `IsMouseOver` is `true`.  It must be on the `ContentPresenter` and not the `Border` because the `ContentPresenter`s are children of the `ItemsControl`'s panel.

Unfortunately I don't think this property has made it to Silverlight yet...

Comment: Yeah...I saw that too, and I'm using ItemsControl as my container which derives from Panel, but the prop isn't available in SL.  Thx

Comment: Nice answer-- this helped me out quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

For a control that uses the Grid as LayoutRoot you can just do something as simple as that within a control itself:

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(this, 999);
```

Answer (score 3):

First find the Maximum ZIndex of all its child elements and then set the new ZIndex.

```
private int MaxZIndex()
{
    int iMax = 0;
    foreach (UIElement element in JIMSCanvas.Children)
    {            
        int iZIndex=Canvas.GetZIndex(element);
        if(iZIndex>iMax)
        {
            iMax = iZIndex;
        }
    }
    return iMax+1;
}
```

Then assign

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(child, MaxZIndex());
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the attached property Zindex is defined in [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas_attachedproperties(VS.95).aspx) and thus is not available in other derivatives of Panel.

The ItemsControl orders the subelements according to the order of the list. The first Item at the bottom of the stack and the last on top. With that given, all you have to do is making sure the selected item is on bottom of the list.

First create an interface for the ordering. Like this:

```
interface IOrderable
    {
        int theZOrder{get;set;}
    }
```

Now implement this in the class you're showing.

When you want to bring a item to the front, give it a high number and give all others a low number.

Al there's left is the actual ordering. Add something like this and you're set:

```
ItemsCont.ItemsSource = 
            ItemsCont.Items.OrderByDesc(t=>((IOrderable)t).theZOrder);
```

Comment: I thought of that at first, but in order for the elements to overlap each other, they'd all have to be children of one big canvas.  I wouldn't expect a z-index in one canvas to have an effect on the z-index of another.  But if I use one big canvas, the elements aren't direct children of it anyway

Comment: Actually, ZIndex does work for other Panel types. Go ahead and try it.

Answer (score 2):

Html works the same way. All the list items must be siblings if you want to lay them out in layers.

I extended the code above so that it will stop if it finds (for example) an ItemsPresenter. If the ContentPresenter doesn't show itself between here and the ItemsPresenter, then fall back on my original code.

```
void setZindex(MyLayeredType layeredObj, int index) 
{
    ContentPresenter sibbling = 
    FindVisualParent<ContentPresenter, ItemsPresenter>(layeredObj);
    if (sibbling != null)
    {
        sibbling.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, index);
    }
    else
    {
        layeredObj.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, index);
    }
}

public static T FindVisualParent<T,C>(this DependencyObject obj)
where T : DependencyObject
where C : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    while (parent != null)
    {
        T typed = parent as T;
        if (typed != null)
        {
            return typed;
        }
        C ceiling = parent as C;
        if (ceiling != null)
            return null;
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

set zIndex of your element in this way

```
var zIndex = 
    ((Panel) element.Parent)
    .Children.Cast<UIElement>()
    .Max(child => Canvas.GetZIndex(child))
    ;

zIndex++;

Canvas.SetZIndex(element, zIndex);
```

- maybe you need to check if zIndex is equal to int.MaxValue then reset "ZIndex"s.
- but this almost never happens