# how to bring canvas above all the other controls

Tags: silverlight

i am working on a  silver light application . i have a  canvas in the  page,i want to show the canvas above all the other  controls or want to bring all the canvas to the front of the page.how can that be done

Comment: Are you using XAML or code? Can you show us what you currently have?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630006/bring-element-forward-z-index-in-silverlight-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it from your main containing control (usually a grid - LayoutRoot) and add it back at the end to ensure it's above all other controls.

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(myCanvas);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myCanvas);
```

Or you can use the insert method to add it at the desired index.