# Problems in diplaying Image on Canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

I have a Canvas on which I have dynamically added some shapes. I now want to add an `Image` over the canvas.

Everything works fine, if I add `Image` out of `Canvas` but when I am trying to add the `Image` on the `Canvas`, the image is not showing up. Maybe it is hidden behind the Shapes drawn on `Canvas`.

My question is how can I bring the `Image` in front of the `Canvas`.

This is how I am adding image :

```
string strUri2 = String.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/MyFirstWPF;component/Images/tt.jpg");
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strUri2));
```

Note-> the shapes on canvas are added before adding the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways:

- change the Z-Index of the `Image` to bring it to the front of the Z-Order on the `Canvas`
- use a container that allows the `Canvas` to be overlaid with the `Image` element (e.g a `Grid`)

If you use the Z-Index method with the Canvas then to do it properly you have to concern yourself with the Z-Index of other elements on the Canvas....because you have to choose a Z-Index value that is bigger than everything else.

You could guess, and just pick a large Z-Index which you think will never be reached by the other elements, or you could scan through the children of the Canvas and find the highest Z-Index used, so that you can always set a higher one....so that you can ensure you "Bring to Front" the Image.

- [BringToFront in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666754/bringtofront-in-wpf)

---

(this is probably the same as what you were using when you say "Out of Canvas")

There's an alternative way which means you don't have to explicitly bother with Z-Indexes, just use a Grid and specify the Canvas and Image as children...they will occupy the same cell, and so overlap each other...the Image being the last child will have the largest implied Z-Index.

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="mycanvas"/>
    <Image x:Name="image1/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
myCanvas.Children.Insert(0,image1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `z-index` of your image higher than other shapes to bring it on top of other shapes like this - `Canvas.SetZIndex(image1, (int)5);`

Refer to these links to know more about z-index - [Controlling z-order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/06/13/controlling-zorder-using-the-zindex-property.aspx), [Z-Index of Canvas](http://www.wpftutorials.com/2011/03/wpf-canvas.html)