# Is it possible to have one component behind and one component above a different grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a project in C# WPF. This is the example code that I am working with:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="topGrid" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Grid Name="bottomGrid" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
ContentGrid c = new ContentGrid();
topGrid.Children.Add(c);

BottomGrid b = new BottomGrid();
bottomGrid.Children.Add(b);

Grid.SetZIndex(topGrid, 1);
```

BottomGrid.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="Blue"/>
```

ContentGrid.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,0,0,-50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,100,-50"/>
</Grid>
```

This means that the BottomGrid (blue) will be behind the ContentGrid (red) and the two rectangles will therefore be above the blue BottomGrid. My question is then:

Is it possible to get the left rectangle (green) to be above the blue BottomGrid while the right rectangle (yellow) is behind it? The right rectangle should still be above the red ContentGrid.

Thanks

Comment: Question is a little confusing. A picture would be great if you could sketch it out.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5671020/4667466) should do the trick. It even uses colored rectangles in a `Grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, I got your requirements right. It's not possible with a single grid (because you would have to push the blue grid right inside the red one). But two grids are possible:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
        <Grid Background="Red">                
            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,100,-50"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid Background="Blue"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,0,0,-50"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here's the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Can't believe I did not think about it before