# Using Canvas in order to BringToFront elements in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Following codes are okey.

```
  <DockPanel>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Name="Button6" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
            <Button Name="Button5" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
            <Button Name="Button4" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Panel.ZIndex="3"/>
            <Button Name="Button3" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Panel.ZIndex="4"/>
            <Button Name="Button2" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Panel.ZIndex="5"/>
            <Button Name="Button1" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Panel.ZIndex="6"/>
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
```

.

```
Panel.SetZIndex(Button2, Panel.GetZIndex(Button1) + Panel.GetZIndex(Button3) + Panel.GetZIndex(Button4) + Panel.GetZIndex(Button5) + +Panel.GetZIndex(Button6))
```

But I want to use more professional code instead of the second code above.

Following coding looks okey. But following code is C#. I need vb.net code. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6044491

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much sense in having six Buttons exactly on top of each other and bringing one of them to front. Why do you want to do that? Anyway, you may simply set ZIndex to 0 for all of them except the one that should be topmost, where you would set ZIndex to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much Clemens. `For Each btn As Button In Canvas1.Children.OfType(Of Button)()
            Panel.SetZIndex(btn, 0)
        Next
        Panel.SetZIndex(Button2, 1)`