# Canvas Stacking Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a Border with some contents and a `Line` on a canvas. The Border + contents are draggable and the `Line` is updated to move with the Border. My problem is that the line is on top of the Border so in some situations it blocks my content. I have tried setting the ZIndex and changed their order in XAML but it doesn't effect anything. I would hazard a guess it is because the `Line` is continually being rendered as it changes shape and for some reason outputs to the screen on top. Any way around this?

**SOME OF MY CODE**

**XAML**

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas"
            MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown"
            MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
            MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove">
            <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="3" Padding="3" Name="bdr"
Background="{StaticResource GradientBackground}" Canvas.ZIndex="99"
                MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftBtnDown">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </Border.RenderTransform>
    <button/>
            </Border>
        </Canvas>
        <Polygon
            Canvas.ZIndex="98"
            Name="SpeechPoly"
            Stroke="Aqua" 
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Fill="{StaticResource GradientBackground}">
        </Polygon>
```

**C#**

```
private void Dragging()
{
...
point = bdr.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
myPoints.RemoveAt(1);
myPoints.RemoveAt(1);

myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X, p.Y + 50));
myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X, p.Y + 25));
SpeechPoly.Points = myPoints;
}
```

Comment: you might be interested in reading this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630006/bring-element-forward-z-index-in-silverlight-wpf

Comment: Hmm tried applying the top answer but the method they listed takes one parameter but the method call doesn't supply one :/

Comment: your polygon is a dependency object for sure, can you find its content presenter with the provided function ?

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPS for you !!! you put a Canvas.ZIndex for your polygon whereas it is NOT in the canvas !!!

Comment: lmao, I act had it in a canvas at one stage and forgotten to remove the ZIndex but tried putting them all in the same canvas (which I hadn't tried before) and works! Thanks once again Vin.

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question.  Put the answer in the . . . answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap work around would be to determine where the line is coming from on the border (i.e. right/left hand side, top/bottom) and move it around the border.

**UPDATED**

```
if (p.X > myPoints[0].X)//right
{
    if (p.Y + bdr.ActualHeight> myPoints[0].Y)//lower
    {
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X, p.Y + 50));
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X, p.Y + 25));
    }
    else//higher
    {
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X, p.Y + bdr.ActualHeight- 50));
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X, p.Y + bdr.ActualHeight - 25));
    }
}
else if (p.X + bdr.ActualWidth > myPoints[0].X)//Middle
{
    if (p.Y + bdr.ActualHeight > myPoints[0].Y)//lower
    {
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + (bdr.ActualWidth / 2) + 25, p.Y));
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + (bdr.ActualWidth / 2), p.Y));
    }
    else if (p.Y + bdr.ActualHeight < myPoints[0].Y)//higher
    {
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + (bdr.ActualWidth / 2) + 25, p.Y + bdr.ActualHeight));
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + (bdr.ActualWidth / 2), p.Y + bdr.ActualHeight));
    }
}
else//left
{
    if (p.Y > myPoints[0].Y)//lower
    {
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + bdr.ActualWidth, p.Y + 50));
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + bdr.ActualWidth, p.Y + 25));
    }
    else//higher
    {
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + bdr.ActualWidth, p.Y + 50));
        myPoints.Add(new Point(p.X + bdr.ActualWidth, p.Y + 25));
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Had to have my `Line` within the same canvas as the border. Seems obvious now... Thanks Vincent!